# Multiple parameters lists and default arguments

Tags: scala

Compiling this code:

```
class Test {

  def f(arg: Int)(defaultArg: String => Unit = println): Unit = ???

  f(42)
}
```

fails with

`` missing argument list for method f in class Test
[error] Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected.
[error] You can make this conversion explicit by writing `f _` or `f(_)(_)` instead of `f`.
[error]     f(42)
[error]      ^
[error] one error found ``

Why does it fail? Does it introduce ambiguity? Is it possible to make it work w/o resorting to single parameters list?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The correct syntax for your case is the following:

```
f(42)()
```

You can make call to f(42) work by defining defaultArg as implicit:

```
def f(arg: Int)(implicit defaultArg: String => Unit = println): Unit = ???
```

Then you can call it:

```
f(42)
```

Comment: Ah, so you have to specify () for parameters list *unless* it is implicit parameters list

Answer (score 0):

So you are passing a `Int` argument to a method and a function that can print it. Now when you say `f(42)` the compiler would see that the function can be applied to the `Int` and result in another function. That is it see this is a case of partially applied function.
So when you make the call `f(42)` the result is another function.So the compiler complains saying that you should either pass in the second argument or treat this result as  a partially applied function.

Consider the following code,

```
val ptln1:String=>Unit = System.out.println _ //Doing this to show the type of the println function
def f(arg: Int)(defaultArg: String => Unit = ptln1): Unit = ???
val t = f(42)()
```

As you can see i have written the types explicitly so it makes sense.
So now you could either pass the function using implicits as below,

```
def f(arg: Int)(implicit defaultArg: String => Unit = println _): Unit = ???
f(42)()
```

Or this without implicits ,

```
  def f(arg: Int)(defaultArg: String => Unit = println _): Unit = ???
  val t = f(42)()
```

Also consider the following optionally if i use a self defined function instead of the `println` . Maybe this will make it clearer.

```
implicit def testPrint(str:String):Unit = ???

   def f(arg: Int)(implicit defaultArg: String => Unit = testPrint): Unit = ???

   val t = f(42)
```

Or without implicits ,

```
   def testPrint(str:String):Unit = ???

   def f(arg: Int)(defaultArg: String => Unit = testPrint): Unit = ???

   val t = f(42)()
```